# Paypal Token Expired

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

How can i detect that Express Checkout token has expired, if a user simple closes the paypal page, also he is not redirected back to my return(cancel) page.

Are ther sending some sort of IPN message ?

Answer (score 0):

No IPN message is sent if the user does not complete che purchase. 
Why check if the token is expired? Paypal already does it.
If you want to check if the transaction occurs rely on the IPN messages and/or on the result of the doExpressCheckout.

Comment: i need to track transation status on my me site. If no IPN message is send, success or cancle link is opened, i dont have any ways to track the status of the trancation.

Comment: IPN is sent when the transaction occurs with a success or a failure. There is no IPN message if there is no transaction. You can handle the status on your backend totally based on what IPN send yo you. btw paypal documentation states: "The SetExpressCheckout API operation returns a token, which is used by other Express Checkout API operations and by the _ExpressCheckout command to identify the transaction. The life of the token is approximately 3 hours." It is not realiable to base the status on the token, you can use the step 5 of express checkout (getExpressCheckoutDetails) to do that

Comment: This answers everything except for what was asked. (referring to "How can i detect that Express Checkout token has expired?"